# Driver is unable to get I/O DMA Adapter

Tags: windows-10, driver, wdk, windows-kernel

My driver for a PCI Bus-Master Device without Scatter/Gather capability calls `IoGetDmaAdapter()`, but fails with `0xFFFFFFFFC0000005 Access Violation`.  This causes a BSOD.

Here's how I set it up:

```
RtlZeroMemory(&deviceDescription, sizeof(DEVICE_DESCRIPTION));
deviceDescription.Master = TRUE; // this is a bus-master device without scatter/gather ability
deviceDescription.Dma32BitAddresses = TRUE; // this device is unable to perform 64-bit addressing
deviceDescription.InterfaceType = InterfaceTypeUndefined;

KdBreakPoint();

deviceDescription.Version = DEVICE_DESCRIPTION_VERSION2;
IoGetDmaAdapter(deviceObject, &deviceDescription, &fakeRegs);
```

Here's my Windows kernel debugging session:

```
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x313:
fffff803`319626a3 488b8424e8000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0E8h]
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x324:
fffff803`319626b4 488d442478      lea     rax,[rsp+78h]
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x34d:
fffff803`319626dd 8b442450        mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+50h]
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x358:
fffff803`319626e8 c684248900000001 mov     byte ptr [rsp+89h],1
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x360:
fffff803`319626f0 c784248000000002000000 mov dword ptr [rsp+80h],2
MyDriver!AllocateHardWareResource+0x36b:
fffff803`319626fb 4c8d44244c      lea     r8,[rsp+4Ch]
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection

*** Fatal System Error: 0x0000007e
                       (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005,0x0000000000000000,0xFFFF9400DE25D4B8,0xFFFF9400DE25CCF0)

WARNING: This break is not a step/trace completion.
The last command has been cleared to prevent
accidental continuation of this unrelated event.
Check the event, location and thread before resuming.
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

A fatal system error has occurred.
```

Before the crash at Guard_Dispatch_iCall_NOP, I see the following call-stack:

```
HalpGetCacheCoherency + 6D
HalGetAdapterV2 + A8
IoGetDmaAdapter + C0
IoGetDmaAdapter + C0
IoGetDmaAdapter + C0
My Call-Site
```

I checked that Physical Device Object has the same address as originally provided to my AddDevice handler.

How should I ask politely to avoid a "Sorry Dave, I can't do that" from [Windows Kernel I/O Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff549220)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When my driver calls into IoGetDmaAdapter(), the driver receives two interface queries via IRP_MN_QUERY_INTERFACE: GUID_BUS_INTERFACE_STANDARD and GUID_DMA_CACHE_COHERENCY_INTERFACE.

GUID_DMA_CACHE_COHERENCY_INTERFACE is new to Windows 10 or Server 2016.

GUID_DMA_CACHE_COHERENCY_INTERFACE query should normally pass to the next driver in the stack. I was making a mistake, setting the status to success, but should have left it alone.